# How to make sure a line of code is executed after another is completed?

Tags: swift, uitableview, notifications, completionhandler

I have a viewControl called PostViewController which has a UITableView of posts. I also have a class called PostCell which defines the UITableViewCell. I made a button function in PostCell called likeButtonClicked to favour a post similar to twitter.

```
@IBAction func likesButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) { NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "likeButtonClicked"), object: nil, userInfo: ["cell":self, "likesButton":likesButton!]) }
```

This is to pass the cell indexPath and the button name to PostViewController. I need indexPath to increase the likes by 1 and the button name to change its image to pink when post is favoured.

I then subscribed to the notification in viewDidLoad of PostViewController.

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(postLiked), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "likeButtonClicked"), object: nil)
```

I then wrote this function in the same viewController

```
  @objc func postLiked(notification: Notification){
    if let cell = notification.userInfo?["cell"] as? UITableViewCell{
        let likesButton = notification.userInfo?["likesButton"] as? SpringButton
        if let indexPath = postsTableView.indexPath(for: cell){
            let post = posts[indexPath.row]
            postId = post.id
            PostAPI.getPostById(postId: postId) { post in
                //Check if the same post were already favoured.
                if !self.liked || self.oldPostId != self.postId{
                    self.newLikes = post.likes + 1
                    self.liked = true
                    self.oldPostId = self.postId
                }else{
                    self.newLikes = self.newLikes - 1
                    self.liked = false
                }
                PostAPI.favourPost(postId: self.postId, likes: self.newLikes) {
                    PostAPI.getPostById(postId: self.postId) { postResponse in
                        let post = postResponse
                        self.posts[indexPath.row] = post
                        let cellNumber = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)
                        self.reloadRowData(cellNumber: cellNumber){
                            if !self.liked{
                                likesButton?.tintColor = .systemPink
                            }else{
                                likesButton?.tintColor = .darkGray
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
func reloadRowData(cellNumber: IndexPath, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    self.postsTableView.reloadRows(at: [cellNumber], with: .none)
    completion()
}
```

Please tell me why the last 4 lines of postLiked function is executed before reloadRowData function, which causes the button to change its color to pink then returns immediately to gray when it should stay pink.

Any help will be most appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the specific problem is your call to `reloadRows`. As the [docs note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows#):

> Reloading a row causes the table view to ask its data source for a new cell for that row. The table animates that new cell in as it animates the old row out. Call this method if you want to alert the user that the value of a cell is changing. If, however, notifying the user is not important—that is, you just want to change the value that a cell is displaying—you can get the cell for a particular row and set its new value.

So this is likely creating an entirely new cell, and then the later code modifies the old cell that is being removed from the table. (So you see the change, and then the cell is removed and replaced.)

I would start by getting rid of the entire `reloadRowData` call.

Generally, though, this code is fragile, and I'd redesign it. The cell should take care of setting the tint colors itself based on the data. You generally shouldn't be reaching into a cell and manipulating its subviews. This will cause you a problem when cells are recycled (for example, when this scrolls off screen). All the configuration should be done in `cellForRow(at:)`, and the cell should observe its Post and update itself when there are changes.

Data should live in the Model. The View should observe the Model and react. The Model should not reach into the View and manipulate anything.

As a side: your `reloadRowData` looks async, but it's not. There's no reason for a completion handler. It could just call `return`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>A table view's `.reloadRows(at:...)` (and `.reloadData()`) functions are ***async*** processes.</s>

So your `reloadRowData()` func is returning *before* the table view actually reloads the row(s).

This is a rather unusual approach - both in using `NotificationCenter` for your cells to communicate with the controller, and in trying to change the button's tint color by holding a reference to the button.

The tint color really should be set in `cellForRowAt`, based on your data source.

---

**Edit**

My description of table view data reloading being *asynchronous* was misleading.

The point I wanted to make was this...

If I change my data, call `.reloadData()`, and then change my data again:

```
    // set myData values
    myData = ["You", "Say", "Hello"]
    
    // call .reloadData here
    tableView.reloadData()

    // change myData values
    myData = ["I", "Say", "Goodbye"]
```

the table view will **not** display "You Say Hello" even though we call `.reloadData()` when those are the values of myData.

Here's a complete, simple example to demonstrate:

```
class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var myData: [String] = ["Some", "Song", "Lyrics"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "c")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row]
        return c
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // call my func when a row is selected
        self.myReload()
    }
    
    func myReload() {
        
        // set myData values
        myData = ["You", "Say", "Hello"]
        
        // call .reloadData here
        tableView.reloadData()

        // change myData values
        myData = ["I", "Say", "Goodbye"]
        
        // table view doesn't reload itself we exit this func
        // so we'll get
        //  I
        //  Say
        //  Goodbye
        
    }
    
}
```

So, among the other issues described by Rob Napier in his answer, your original code was trying to change the tint color of an object in a cell ***before*** the table reloaded its data.

Comment: `reloadRows(at:)` and `reloadData` aren't async. They operate synchronously. (`reloadRowData` also isn't async.) But it looks like `getPostById` is.

Comment: @RobNapier - hmmm... I imagine I'm just not explaining it correctly. If I call `.reloadData()` and then modify my data source, that modification takes place *before* the table reloads its data, as shown in this simple example: https://pastebin.com/0kVAL9Fa -- So I guess it should be worded "the table view does not update itself until the main thread becomes available"?

Comment: @DonMag It's unrelated to when the main thread becomes available. If you're modifying the data on a non-main thread, it's undefined behavior anyway. The point is that the cells won't be redrawn until the next event loop. To your example, the calls to `cellForRowAt` may not be called until later, is true, but "asynchronous" is misleading here, because of how it interacts with things like `beginUpdates` animations. It's not on another thread or coroutine or anything. It's more like `setNeedsDisplay` impacts things later, but we wouldn't call `setNeedsDisplay` asynchronous.

Comment: @D.A. See answer below. Start by getting rid of the entire `reloadRowData` call. It's not helpful and is breaking you. Then move on from there.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rob

Comment: Good edits. Much clearer now.